# MYSQL Return multiple child rows from parent table query

Tags: mysql

I am working on building a database structure and need my query result to look something like this :

`[{ id : 11, customer : "John", orders : [{ order_id : 1, product : "milk"}, { order_id : 2, product : "oranges"}] }]`

My initial idea was to store customers in one table named "customer" and then orders in another table named "orders" then when I query customers I could `JOIN`, but the issue that rises is that when I `JOIN` the multiple order queries override each other and I am left with : `[{ id : 11, customer : "John", order_id : 1, product : "milk" }]`

In the future I will have multiple child elements to "customer."

Comment: You'd aggregate slave table then join main.

Comment: Use limit in your Query.

Comment: I found this answer works for my situation -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/37474200/18385744